# Area code creating apple ID

Tags: apple-id

I'm trying to create a new apple ID. I live in the Netherlands but have a UK number. Every time I try to type in my number (with United Kingdom selected), it tells me "please choose an area code which matches the name of the country". My mobile phone doesn't have an area code. What do I type in this box? I've tried the first 2-3 digits of my phone number with and without +44 or 0044.

Answer (score 4):

UK numbers are all 11 digits, or country code plus 10 digits, omitting the leading zero.

so either
**01234 567 890**
or
**+44 1234 567 890**
[spaces only for legibility].

UK mobiles all start with 07 [or +44 7] - so the 'area code' is 07 *nnn* or +44 7 *nnn*

Just for extra information, adding your own country code to all domestic numbers does not affect call cost whilst in that territory, these days the systems are smart enough to figure it out.

00 international designations are only for dialling from landlines which can't use the + symbol.

Comment: How does this answer OP's question? Phone number on the AppleID registration form consist of three fields: Country code, Area code, Phone. The Country code is easy (it is a dropdown input anyway), but how to split the remaining 10 digits across the two other fields?

Comment: @TMG - without country code, it's the first 5 digits; with country code it's the first 4, because you omit the zero. Not sure it was that difficult to extract from what I wrote.

Comment: I've put the first 3 digits of my phone number as area code and it worked. However the form validation is really crappy there: The area code field turned red with no explicit validation error displayed, yet I was still able to click Continue and it proceeded just fine.

Comment: This just helped my colleague create his apple id. It is still happening, from a brand new macbook.

Answer (score 3):

Had me scratching my head wondering what I was doing wrong until I saw the last comment on this post. Thanks @TMG

> I've put the first 3 digits of my phone number as area code and it worked. However the form validation is really crappy there: The area code field turned red with no explicit validation error displayed, yet I was still able to click Continue and it proceeded just fine.

Comment: Why downvotes? It worked for me as well... Example: let's say my phone number is +48 500 600 700. I tried (area code and phone number): 48 and 500 600 700, 048 and 500 600 700, 0048 500 600 700, +48 500 600 700 - nothing worked. After reading this comment, I tried: 500 and 600 700 and... it worked. Apple, shame on you!